# $y' = 3y^{\frac{2}{3}}$ non unique solution at $(1,1)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

When considering the differential equation $y' = 3y^{\frac{2}{3}}$, I can find solutions $y = (t-a)^3, t > a$ and $y= (t-b)^3, t < b$. Also $y = 0$ is a solution.

I am suppose to show in reference to these two solutions that there are infinite number of solutions to this differential equation satisfying $y(1) = 1$, and why this does not contradict existence and uniqueness.

Problem is, for $t > 0, y > 0$ $f$ and $f_y$ are continuous, so in the domain $y > 0$ the solution should be unique. Could someone explain my flaw in logic>

Comment: The solution with $y>0$ is only $y=(t-a)^3$, $t>a$

Comment: Related:  [The Norton's dome suggesting non-determinism in classical physics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426755/the-nortons-dome-suggesting-non-determinism-in-classical-physics)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $f(t,y)= 3y^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is continuous, the equation $y^\prime= 3y^{\frac{2}{3}}$ has at least one solution according to [Peano existence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem?wprov=sfti1) whatever the initial condition is.

However, $f$ is not Lipschitz continuous in $y$ around $0$. Hence we can’t apply the uniqueness part of [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem?wprov=sfti1) around $y=0$. Uniqueness is however true around $t_0$ if $y(t_0) \neq 0$.

And indeed, we can see that for any $b < 0$,

$$y(t)=\begin{cases}
(t-b)^3 & t < b\\
0 & b \le t \le 0\\
t^3 & t > 0
\end{cases}$$ is a solution with the initial condition $y(1)=1$.